# Call a class activity at onReceive to run at background

Tags: android, android-activity

i made an alarm clock and everything works fine.

Inside public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver i have the following the working code bellow. My question is how to call an activity class to run parallel(background) with ringtone?

Also i tried the code bellow but it redirects me to the reffered class, how can avoid it and call and run this class activity but to do not change the user interface?

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver

{

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

        if (alarmUri == null)
        {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }

        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();

Intent i = new Intent(context, testactivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

}
}
```

I have also create the testactivity java class with the code bellow:

```
public class testactivity extends Activity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.testactivity);

        Toast.makeText(this, "this is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: what problem you are facing here? explain?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do not show the UI of targeted activity class..
Simply added the following code to android manifest file:

```
<activity
            android:name=".testactivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
```